# Input file inside updatepanel and postback trigger asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I am using an input file inside an UpdatePanel and it works very well. but using UpdatePanel PostBackTrigger, ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript doen't work.

If I don't use PostBackTrigger, ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript works but the input file doesn't.

I'm using ASP Web Forms with C#

Here's the source code.

.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UploadFile.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.UploadFile" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up_upload" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_upload" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <input type="file" id="file_test" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="btn_upload" runat="server" Text="Subir" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="btn_upload_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

.cs

```
protected void btn_upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string message = "file not uploaded!";
        if (file_test.PostedFile != null)
        {
            string fn = file_test.PostedFile.FileName;
            string only_path = Server.MapPath(".");

            file_test.PostedFile.SaveAs(only_path + "//Images//" + fn);

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(up_upload, up_upload.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('server path: ' + '" + only_path.Replace("\\", "\\\\") + "');", true);
            message = "file uploaded!";

        }

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(up_upload, up_upload.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('" + message + "');", true);

        up_upload.Update();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(up_upload, up_upload.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('" + ex.Message + "');", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I need to send back to client a javasript function to show a message after file upload, but by some reason the RegisterStartupScript is not compatible with UpdatePanel Triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I used ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript instead of ScriptManager.RegisterstartupScript when I make a full page post back.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(up_upload.GetType(), 
Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "<script>alert('" + message + "');</script>");
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

FileUpload using asp.net file uploader control always requires **full page postback** request.

This is a limitation of the XmlHttpRequest component used in all AJAX frameworks for asynchronous calls to the application.
I suggest you two solutions:

1. **Give a full page post back**(**i.e. do not use file upload in updatepanel)
2. If you **do** **not** want a complete postback, try other solutions like [Dropzone](http://dropzone.js) file uploader plugin for uploading files. I always use this when I want a cool file uploading interface. It is very easy to use . Refer its documentation for its use or try [this](http://codepedia.info/2015/03/using-dropzone-js-file-image-upload-in-asp-net-webform-c/) link to learn.

Believe me it is very easy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm willing to make a full post back to upload the file. Is there a way to send javascript code to client doing a full page post back?